# Append file content to the top instead of bottom?

Tags: php, html

i have a form that the staff can fill to send their message to our updates page. My code is

```html
$filename = "files/armaupdates";
$text = $_POST['update'];

$updatesep = "<hr><br><hr><br>";

$fp = fopen($filename, "a+");

if($fp){
 fwrite($fp, $text);
 fwrite($fp, $updatesep);
 fclose($fp);
 echo "Updates has been written!";
}
else {
 echo "Error!";
}
```

I'm going insane since i want the text to be at the top of the file instead of the bottom, anyone?

Comment: How about you use file_get_contents, explode the contents based on new line, reverse the array, append to the array, reverse it back, and then join on new lines?

Comment: There's a couple of ways to do this, but they all involve rewriting the whole file with your prepended content on top. There's no flag to prepend to a file (like there is `a+` to append to a file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filename = "files/armaupdates";
$text = $_POST['update'];

$updatesep = "<hr><br><hr><br>";
$content = file_get_contents($filename);

$fp = fopen($filename, "w");

if($fp){
    fwrite($fp, ($text . $updatesep . $content));
    fclose($fp);
    echo "Updates has been written!";
}
else {
    echo "Error!";
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked, thank you bud!

Answer (score 0):

Just prepend the contents with the new data:

```
$updatedContents = $text . $updatesep . file_get_contents($filename);
```

Giving you code of:

```
$filename = "files/armaupdates";
$text = $_POST['update'];

$updatesep = "<hr><br><hr><br>";

$updatedContents = $text . $updatesep . file_get_contents($filename);

$fp = fopen($filename, "a+");

if($fp){
    fwrite($fp, $updatedContents);
    fclose($fp);
    echo "Updates has been written!";
}
else {
    echo "Error!";
}
```